# drawableLeft/Right etc. doesn't work with Theme.MaterialComponents

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

When using theme for Activity `Theme.MaterialComponents....` if I want to use `drawableLeft/Right` etc. with a button they are not shown. But if I use theme `Base.Theme.AppCompat` they worked as expected.
Here is Button:

```
       <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test Button"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_envelope"/>
```

And this is how it looks with theme `Base.Theme.MaterialComponents`
[image]

And this is with `Base.Theme.AppCompat`
[image]

How can I make `drawableLeft` work with `Base.Theme.MaterialComponents` theme?

Comment: Use a `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` with `app:iconGravity` and `app:icon`

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a [**`MaterialButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) with the **`app:icon`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
      app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
      ../>
```

[image: Screenshot of an outlined button with an icon]

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
    ../>
```

[image: Screenshot of a filled button with an icon]

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
    ../>
```

[image: Screenshot of a borderless button with an icon]

Use the **`app:iconGravity`** to config `start|end|textStart|textEnd`.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:iconGravity="end"
    ../>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like your new edit to your answer had overridden my previous edit to your answer - could you merge the edits together? Thanks!

Comment: @Edric he can't. If you think those edits were that important, you have to apply them again

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yep, I know that you can't merge edits. At most, a rollback could be done.